# Eigenvalues of block matrix where blocks are related.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find eigenvalues of following block matrix $M$ in terms of eigenvalues of matrix $A$?

$M=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B  \\ 
B & O  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

Where matrices $A$,$B$ are symmetric matrices.Also $B=A+I_n$ and $O$ is zero matrix of order $n$

Comment: You will find information on this by looking up "saddle point problem". In general, $B\neq B^T$, so you may be able to simplify the results you find. Sherman-Morrisson formula may be helpful too if$A$ is invertible.

Comment: The following holds: $\det(M-\lambda I_{2n}) = \det( (A-\lambda I_n)(-\lambda I_n) - (A+I_n)^2)=0$. I don't think it can be factorised, but maybe it helps anyway.

Comment: OK,thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we diagonalize $A = SDS^{-1}$ with $S^TS=I$ and $D$ diagonal. Then
$$
\pmatrix{S^{-1}&0\\0&S^{-1}} M \pmatrix{S&0\\0&S}
=\pmatrix{D & D+I \\D+I & 0}.
$$
Applying a suitable permutation $P$, we obtain the block diagonal structure
$$
P\pmatrix{D & D+I \\D+I & 0}P^{-1} =
\pmatrix{ \lambda_1 & \lambda_1+1& \\
\lambda_1& 0 \\
&&&\lambda_2& \lambda_2+1\\
&&&\lambda_2+1 & 0 \\
&&&&&\ddots
}
$$
with $\lambda_i$ denoting the eigenvalues of $A$. These small matrices
$$\pmatrix{ \lambda_i & \lambda_i+1& \\
\lambda_i+1& 0 }
$$
have characteristic polynomials
$$
t^2 -\lambda_i t -(\lambda_i+1)^2=0,
$$whose roots are then the eigenvalues of $M$.

Comment: What is permutation matrix $P$ is?